# What does it mean when ECOS can't solve my SOCP with ~25,000 optimization variables?

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, cvxpy

tl;dr On a convex optimization problem with about 25,000 variables, ECOS runs to max_iters and terminates with the following error:

```
SolverError: Solver 'ECOS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
```

What does this mean?

I am trying to solve a convex optimization problem in cvxpy, where the setup is as follows:

```
# <table> is a contingency table with 3 columns where the first two columns are unique item ids, and the third column describes the frequency of co-occurrence

import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

theta = cp.Variable([196, 10], nonneg=True)
phi = cp.Variable([10], nonneg=True) 
Q = cp.Parameter([2548, 10], nonneg=True) 
Q.value = np.ones([196, 10])/10

obj_func = 0
for m, row in enumerate(table):
    i, j, freq = row
    obj_func += freq * Q[m,:] * (cp.log(theta[i,:]) + cp.log(theta[j,:]) + cp.log(phi)- cp.log(Q[m,:]))

objective = cp.Maximize(obj_func)
constraints = [
    cp.sum(phi) == 1,
    cp.sum(theta, axis=0) == 1,
]

problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
opt_val = problem.solve()
```

When run with `verbose=True` and `max_iters=500`, the output looks like:

```
ECOS 2.0.7 - (C) embotech GmbH, Zurich Switzerland, 2012-15. Web: www.embotech.com/ECOS

It     pcost       dcost      gap   pres   dres    k/t    mu     step   sigma     IR    |   BT
 0  +0.000e+00  -1.108e+05  +1e+06  1e+00  1e+00  1e+00  1e+00    ---    ---    0  0  - |  -  - 
 1  -1.571e+04  -1.265e+05  +1e+06  7e-01  1e+00  1e+00  9e-01  0.2387  5e-01   2  2  2 |  0  2
 2  -7.070e+04  -1.814e+05  +8e+05  8e-01  1e+00  2e+00  7e-01  0.3791  3e-01   1  2  2 |  1  0
 3  -1.869e+05  -2.975e+05  +5e+05  9e-01  1e+00  2e+00  4e-01  0.6988  5e-01   2  3  2 |  4  1
...
497  +4.782e+08  +4.782e+08  +4e-07  2e-03  5e-12  3e-04  3e-13  0.3208  9e-01   1  1  0 | 16  5
498  +4.782e+08  +4.782e+08  +4e-07  2e-03  5e-12  3e-04  3e-13  0.9791  1e+00   2  1  0 | 27  0
499  +4.782e+08  +4.782e+08  +4e-07  2e-03  5e-12  3e-04  3e-13  0.5013  1e+00   1  1  0 | 21  3
500  +4.782e+08  +4.782e+08  +4e-07  2e-03  5e-12  3e-04  3e-13  0.9791  1e+00   1  1  0 | 30  0
Maximum number of iterations reached, recovering best iterate (497) and stopping.

RAN OUT OF ITERATIONS (reached feastol=1.6e-03, reltol=8.3e-16, abstol=4.0e-07).
Runtime: 314.146930 seconds.
```

As far as I can tell this is a perfectly standard convex optimization problem. However, when I run ECOS on it, I reach max_iters without it converging. Repeating with `max_iters = 500` (as compared to the default of 67) did not solve the issue.

My question is, why does this happen? What is ECOS trying to tell me? Is my problem infeasible? Is it just that there are too many variables to handle?

Comment: hi @Daniel Tan, Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Waging a guess, I suspect this comes down to scaling. The primal and dual cost are very close together, the gap is small. Maybe the solver tolerances are set too tight for this instance?

Things to try:

- Try rescaling your formulation, so that all involved constants have similar magnitudes.
- Have a look at the solution computed by ECOS. It might very well be ok - in that case you'd just have to adjust the termination criteria of the solver.